# How to lock cpu priority of a process and block it from changing the priority itself?

Tags: windows, windows-10, process, priority

I have an application that is programmed to change it's priority to high. Even if I switch it back to normal or lower, it changes back after some time. How can I block this behavior? How can I force process' cpu priority so that it can't change the priority itself? The closest solution I've come to so far was a script that checks the priority and changes it if necessary, however this solution doesn't force the priority for all the time.

Comment: Is this application run as an administrator?  You might be able to adjust the privs that the user running the process has but what do you think the code is going to do when it requests that the priority changes and that request fails?

Comment: No, it's not being run as an administrator. I don't know how it will behave, I have no source code of this app.